# Python Assignment problem about voter turnout: class and object and function

Tags: python, function, class, object

```
# implement County class here
class County:
  def __init__(self, name,population,voters):
    self.name=name
    self.population=population
    self.voters=voters

  # implement the function here

def highest_turnout(data):

highest_turnout = (data[0].voters)/(data[0].population)
for county in data:
    if (county.voters/county.population) > highest_turnout:
        highest_turnout= county
return highest_turnout

allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)
data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]  

result = highest_turnout(data) # do not change this line!
print(result) # prints the output of the function
# do not remove this line!
```

I have to make a python function  in which returns the highest voter turnout  I am only a beginner to programming and the class resources are not really helping. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Directions:
● First, find the County that has the highest turnout, i.e. the highest percentage of the population who voted, using the objects’ population and voters attributes
● Then, return a tuple containing the name of the County with the highest turnout and the
percentage of the population who voted, in that order; the percentage should be
represented as a number between 0 and 1

I have already written the class.

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'County'

I have gotten this error. I think my class is right but I am not so sure what to do with this function. The instruction also says to return the county's name and highest voter turnout in a tuple, but I am not so sure how. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: We can't help you with your code if you don't show it to us..

Comment: Hello, Jennifer, welcome to StackOverflow. For questions seeking debugging help, please provide a [mcve]. Since you are new, I suggest checking out [help] and [ask] as well. In general, you should provide some code that reproduces the problem removing unnecessary details *in the question itself as formatted text*. Here's some info on how to format questions in Markdown: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help If you are getting an error, post the complete error message as well.

Comment: I have been trying to add my code for a while now but since this is my first time trying to add code, it is kind of confusing. Could you please hold on a while?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
highest_turnout = (data[0].voters)/(data[0].population)
for county in data:
    if (county.voters/county.population) > highest_turnout:
        highest_turnout= county
```

So, let's consider the first (well, second - the one concerning `data[1]`, since the `data[0]` iteration isn't relevant here) iteration of this loop. `highest_turnout` was just defined as a `float` of voters / population. You're comparing that to another `float`, of another country's voters / population. Make sense.

Now let's consider that `voters / population` is higher for `data[1]` than for `data[0]`. So, the `if` condition gets triggered. `highest_turnout` is set to `data[1]`, which is the current value of `county`.

We continue to the next iteration, for `data[2]`, and you get your error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'County'
```

In the first iteration, `highest_turnout` was a `float`, and you were using the operator `>` between two `floats`. But *now*, `highest_turnout` is a `County`, not a `float` - when you assigned it a new value inside the `if` statement, you changed what type it is. And since `County` isn't a type of number, python doesn't know how to compare it to a `float`. Thus the error you see here.

The solution is to make `highest_turnout` the value it was being compared to, rather than the country those values came from:

```
highest_turnout = county.voters / county.population
```

An alternate solution would be to keep `highest_turnout` a country the entire time:

```
highest_turnout = data[0]
for county in data:
    if (county.voters/county.population) > (highest_turnout.voters/highest_turnout.population):
        highest_turnout = county
```

You just need to make sure you're not changing the type of any variable without realizing it.

Comment: I changed my highest_turnout = data[0] but I still get the error message that I cannot use < operation on floats. What do u suggest that I do? Also, how do I return a tuple at the end with the county's name and their highest turnout percentage? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at the entire code blocks I gave you - you need to make sure that both sides of the `>` are numbers. Run through your code manually, maybe even with a debugger, and keep note of *exactly what type* each of your variables is at any given time. As for returning a tuple - you might want to keep two variables (`highest_turnout` and `highest_turnout_county`) and change *both of them at the same time*. Then, at the end, return both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, instead of using a loop to find the maximum turnout county, use the max function:

```
class County:

    def __init__(self, name, population, voters):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population
        self.voters = voters

    def get_turnout(self):
        # return the turnout as a number between 0 - 1.
        return self.voters / self.population

def highest_turnout(counties):
    max_county = max(counties, key=lambda c: c.get_turnout())
    return (max_county.name, max_county.get_turnout())
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with these variables:

```
highest_county = data[0].name
highest_turnout = data[0].voters / data[0].population
```

and then call for:

```
return highest_county, highest_turnout
```